# Using inline function with constant arguments in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, equation

This is a part of my code.

```
clear all;
clc;
p = 50;
t = [-6 : 0.01 : 6];
f = inline('(t+2).*sin(t)', 't')
v = inline('3*f(p*t+2)','t','f','p')
plot(t,f(t));
v(t,f,p);
figure;
plot(t,v(t,f,p));
```

Here I have two questions.

1. Why I have to pass `p` into the function `v` even though `p` is a constant which has already declared ?
2. How I can get an expression for `v` completely in terms of `t` as `3*[(50*t+2)*sin(50*t+2)]` or in its simplified form ?

**Update**

 This is an update for the second question
Let

```
f(x) = 1 + x - x^2
g(x) = sin(x)
```

If I give f(g(x)), I wanna get the output in words, like this

```
f(g(x)) = (cos(X))^2 + sin(x)
```

not in numerical value. Is there any function capable to do that?

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Why do I have to pass `p` to `v` even though `p` is a constant which has already been declared?

Well, a MATLAB's inline function object has an [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) wrapper, so the only variables in its scope are those which were automatically captured from the expression or explicitly specified.

In other words, if you want `v` to recognize `p`, you have no other option but declaring it when creating the `inline` object and passing it to `v` explicitly. The same goes for `f` as well!

> 2) How I can get an expression for v completely in terms of t as 3*[(50*t+2)*sin(50*t+2)] or in its simplified form?

Use anonymous functions, like Shai suggested. They are more powerful, more elegant and much faster. For instance:

```
v = @(t)(3*(50*t+2)*sin(50*t+2))
```

Note that if you use a name, which is already in use by a variable, as an argument, the anonymous function will treat it as an argument first. It does see other variables in the scope, so doing something like `g = @(x)(x + p)` is also possible.

**EDIT #1:**
Here's another example, this time a function of a function:

```
x = 1:5;
f = @(x)(x .^ 3);        %// Here x is a local variable, not as defined above
g = @(x)(x + 2);         %// Here x is also a local variable
result = f(g(x));
```

or alternatively define yet another function that implements that:

```
h = @(x)f(g(x));         %// Same result as h = @(x)((x + 2) .^ 3)
result = h(x);
```

The output should be the same.

**EDIT #2:**

If you want to make an anonymous function out of the expression string, concatenate the '@(x)' (or the correct anonymous header, as you see fit) to the beginning and apply `eval`, for example:

```
expr = '(x + 2) .^ 3';
f = eval(['@(x)', expr]) %// Same result as f = @(x)((x + 2) .^ 3)
```

Note that you can also do `char(f)` to convert it back into a string, but you'll have to manually get rid of the `'@(...)'` part.

**EDIT #3:**
If you're looking for a different solution, you can explore the [Symbolic Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/). For example, try:

```
syms x
f(x) = x + 2
g(x) = x ^ 3
```

or can also use [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html), like so:

```
f(x) = sym('x + 2');
g(x) = sym('x ^ 3');
```

Use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) to substitute values and evaluate the symbolic expression.

Comment: How i can get a simplified form of a `function of a function` in MATLAB, like, `f(x) = x^3`, `g(x) = (X+2)`, `f(g(x)) = (x+2)^3`.  If I give `f(g(x))` as input I want `(x+2)^3` in the output.  Any MATLAB function for equation simplification...? Not necessary it should be using `inline` function...

Comment: @noufal The principle is pretty much covered in Shai's answer, but I've also added a clarification in my answer.

Comment: Ok. I understood it can give the output values of `f(g(X))`, But I want the put as `(x+2)^3` as a string...

Comment: Not completely...Is there any function in symbolic math tool box for doing the same...?

Comment: @noufal What do you mean? Doing what exactly? Please see my 3rd edit.

Comment: You can get the effect you want using symbolic functions. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 3):

How about using [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b):

```
p = 50;
t = -6:0.01:6;
f = @(x) (x+2).*sin(x);
v = @(x) 3*f(p*x+2);
figure;
subplot(1,2,1); plot( t, f(t) ); title('f(t)');
subplot(1,2,2); plot( t, v(t) ); title('v(t)');
```

Is this what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a constant into an `inline` can be done during its definition.
Instead of

```
p = 50;
v = inline('3*f(p*t+2)','t','f','p')
```

You can write

```
p = 50;
v = inline(  sprintf('3*f(%f*t+2)', p), 't','f')
```